# Issue with creating multiple checkbox on a fly

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jframe, jcheckbox

I am trying to read all the file name from a specific folder and trying to create multiple checkbox in JFrame with the same name. So, if there are 5 files in the folder, application should show 5 checkboxes in the frame.

Here is my code.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    File folder = new File("C://Tests");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
          JCheckBox checkbox[i] = new JCheckBox(listOfFiles[i].getName());

        }
```

But I am getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from JCheckBox to JCheckBox[]". Can someone please tell me what am I doing incorrect ?

Appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define and initialise the array first...

```
JCheckBox checkbox[] = new JCheckBox[listOfFiles.length];
```

Then fill it...

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    }
    checkbox[i] = new JCheckBox(listOfFiles[i].getName());
}
```

If you want to be able to access the array later on your program, you will need to make the array an instance field...

```
public class ... {
    //...
    private JCheckBox checkbox[];
```

Then initialise it when you know how many files you have...

```
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
checkbox[] = new JCheckBox[listOfFiles.length];
```

Frankly, a simpler solution would be to use some kind `List`, like an `ArrayList`.  See [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this.

1. Declare the array outside the loop; something like-> JCheckBox checkbox[] = new JCheckBox[listOfFiles.length]
2. Inside the loop, keep the checkbox instance in the array -> checkbox[j] = new JCheckBox(listOfFiles[i].getName());